# write a Boolean expression builder in gwt

Tags: gwt

I want to build a Boolean expression builder in gwt. Something like the following:-

Let's say that the Boolean expression allows only a finite number of unique operands. These operands could take arguments if necessary

E.g.

IsSunny("today") AND IsNotRaining("evening")

IsLeapYear("2012") AND IsFullMoon("today")

There is only a finite set of operands. E.g. IsSunny, IsNotRaining, IsLeapYear, IsFullMoon.

I want to build a GWT UI that allows the client to build such Boolean expressions quickly.
Only the predefined set of operands are supported. Each operand can have different number of arguments and the UI ,use enforce the type and number of arguments. Parenthesis is also allowed.

What would be a good way to build such an UI?
Does GWT have any in built support for it?

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: No, you have not a way to do that easily. Maybe you can get some java code from other project for that purpose (in the case it were any) written in java and re-use a good portion of that code.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: I'm the author of this project but... http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/ is sort of similar and is written in GWT.

At the moment I've only published the JS friendly version but I'd be happy to make a GWT version available.

Is aimed towards SQL but it is the only thing in this direction that I know of.

I'm up for sharing tips if you want to write it from scratch.

Comment: Why a warning? Do you have legal rights in regard to building boolean expression builders?

Comment: Warning because stackoverflow doesn't like too much self promotion